# Downloading binary files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-http, open-uri

I am able to download my file, but I end up with a file that says it cannot be executed on my version of Windows.  Here is my code:

```
  Net::HTTP.start(url_base) do |http|
    if response.code == '200'

      self.size = response['content-length'].to_i

      local_file = save_dir + File::SEPARATOR + strip_file_name(url_path)

      if !application_exists?(local_file, response['content-length'].to_i) || overwrite_file?
        build_display
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar.new(response['content-length'].to_i, PROGRESSBAR_SIZE_WIDTH)

        File.open(local_file, 'w') { |f|
          http.get(URI.escape(url_path)) do |str|
            f.write str
            @counter += str.length
            @window.setpos(PROGRESSBAR_LOCATION_TOP, 1)
            @window << (self.progress_bar.show(@counter)).center(WINDOW_WIDTH - 2)
            @window.refresh

            char = @window.getch
            http.finish if char == 'c' # cancel download
          end
        }
      end

    end
  end
```

If I download using open-uri:

```
       file = open(url,
         :content_length_proc => lambda { |content_length|
           if content_length && 0 < content_length
             self.progress_bar = ProgressBar.new(content_length, PROGRESSBAR_SIZE_WIDTH)
           end
         },
         :progress_proc       => lambda { |size|
           #@counter += str.length
           @window.setpos(PROGRESSBAR_LOCATION_TOP, 1)
           @window << (self.progress_bar.show(size)).center(WINDOW_WIDTH - 2)
           @window.refresh

           char = @window.getch
           f.close if char == 'c' # cancel download
         },
         :read_timeout        => 10)
    FileUtils::cp(file, local_file)
```

Everything works....the problem is, I need to be able to cancel the download mid-stream.  How can I a) download using net::http in a 'single-chunk' style, as I think open-uri does, or b) cancel a download mid-stream using open-uri?

Comment: Did you try to replace `w` with `wb` in `File.open(local_file, 'w')` (*b* for binary)?

Comment: Thank you so much!  If you submit this as an actual answer I will select it.